Is "the medication is dying down" the opposite of "the medication is kicking in"?
My son had allergy and he took medication for it. It took a few hours for us to see the result. At that time, I would say "the medication is kicking in".
When you took a painkiller, you can see the result right away but after a while the pain is coming back. At that time, Can I say "the painkiller is dying down"?
Is "the medication is dying down" the opposite of "the medication is kicking in"?

"Kicking in' is very informal and conversational. 'Taking effect' or 'starting to work' would be more formal.

Once the painkiller kicks in, the pain dies down.   When you spray water on a fire, the fire dies down.  When a gale lessens, the wind dies down.  Traffic noise dies down in the middle of the night.   "Dies down" is not synonymous with "becomes less effective".

Relevant usage chart.  Medication usually takes effect and wears off.

I would say either
"The effect of the medicine/medication is fading."
or
"The medicine/medication is wearing off."
I think "dying down" would be understood, but it sounds odd.
